# Positioning chechboxes in lines, say of 4 CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, position

how to use css for positioning my checkboxes in lines let's say of 4. For now the're displaying all in one line.

I tried with floating left and margin but it's not working the way I do it.

I have 7 groups of lists like below in my form

HTML:

```
<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj60">
<form action="mailto:kontakt@2know.pl" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<div id="Oobj58">
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="fitness" />fitness<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="gym" />siłownia<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="siata" />siatkówka<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="noga" />piłka nożna<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="kosz" />koszykówka<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="zima" />sporty zimowe<br />


    </div>

    </form> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Oobj58 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  z-index: 43;
  text-align: left;
  left: 12.25em;
  top: 23.00em;
  display: none;

}
```

class 'Oobj' is empty. I needed it for another jq code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj60">
<form action="mailto:kontakt@2know.pl" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<div id="Oobj58">

<ul>
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="fitness"  />fitness </li>
   <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="gym" />siłownia</li>
   <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="siata" />siatkówka</li>
   <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="noga" />piłka nożna</li>
   <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="kosz" />koszykówka</li>
   <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="zima" />sporty zimowe</li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    </form> </div>



#Oobj58 {

  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Open Sans;

  text-align: left;
  left: 12.25em;
  top: 23.00em;

}
#Oobj58 ul li { display:inline; margin-left:10px; }
```